# Why are my questions and answers showing identicons instead of my profile pic?

Tags: bug, profile-picture, gravatar

I have set a profile picture:

[image]

---

[image]

---

Yet my answers/questions show an identicon.

[image]

Hovering over the identicon shows my profile picture again

[image]

Why's this happening? Same behaviour is consistent across the network and in Incognito mode